# Internet connection by wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a hunch someone is logging on to my wifi. I already know how to see who is currently using my wifi, but can I somehow find out who was using my wifi, lets say, yesterday?

Comment: Please post your router/AP model for more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the only thing you can do is to check your routers or access points web interface for a connection log.

Answer (score 0):

Does your router have a log file?

While I have to say that a MAC address you find there won't give you a real chance to identify the one?

You really should set/change your WiFi password.